# How to use multiple models to one view

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, view, model, entity

I have several data tables / Entities (APRICOT BANANA, LEMON) in the same EDMX and each table has multiple columns (Name, Quantity, Date, Sort)

In a view, I have a drop-down list (DropDownList) which contains ("A", "B" and "C")

What I want to do:

In my drop down list:
When I selected the value A poster I down my drop down list (in the same view) Table data APRICOT

or

When I selected the value I B appears at the bottom of my combo (in the same order) the data from the table BANANA

or

When I selected the value C i appears at the bottom of my combo (in the same order) the data from the table BANANA

Are you can give me a sample code this class, the controller and the view? Sorry I'm a beginner! thank you

Thank you very much for your help

Jeremy

Answer (score 0):

Create a new viewmodel class which will take all the data you need and pass that viewmodel  to the view. 
You can then display the data from the viewmodel based on the dropdown list selected.

Fruit.cs

```
public class Fruit
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

FruitViewModel.cs

```
public class FruitViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Fruit> Fruits { get; set; }

    public FruitViewModel(IEnumerable<Fruit> fruit)
    {
        Fruits = fruits
    }
}
```

Controller.cs

```
public ActionResult FruitView()
{
   var fruits = //get your data here
   return View(new FruitViewModel(fruits));
}
```

View.cs

```
@model FruitViewModel

@Html.DropDownList("FruitTypeId", new SelectList(Model.Fruits , "Id", "Name"), "Select one")
```

Based on the selected Id you can display the value you need using Javascript

Comment: Hello Dakshal Raijada

Thank you to answer me, but are what you can give me a sample code this class, the controller and the view?

Sorry I'm a beginner!

thank you

Comment: Thank you very much for your help I'm getting an idea ... but I do not see the relationship between the different names of my tables (APRICOT, LEMON and BANANA) the value of my DropDownList selection?

Comment: If there are three different entities then the view model can accept three entities and the view can have dropdown based on the number of entities in the view model.